# Looping through all possible strings of length n

Tags: c, cstring, c-strings

I have a program I am writing that has to loop through all possible strings up to size n. Here is the code for it.

```
int len, endlen = atoi(argv[2]);
int i, j, k;
f = fopen(argv[1], "wb");
for (len = 0; len < endlen; len++)
{
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for (k = 32; k < 127; k++)
        {
            entry.len = len;
            string[i] = k;
            memcpy(entry.string, string, 65);
            sha256(string, entry.outbuf, len);
            fwrite(&entry, sizeof(struct hashentry), 1, f);
            fflush(f);
        }
    }
    printf("\rLength done: %d of %d", len, endlen);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

It is coming back with just modifying one index of the string. It needs to do something a lot like counting in binary..

```
000
001
010 <--It moved over
011 <--Now it modified the previous one
100 <--moved again
101 <--Modifying previous
110
111 <--...etc
```

Any help?

*edit: What I need is something that will give me all strings from size=1 to size=endlen. This would be like

```
"a"
"aa"
"aaa"
"aaaa"
"aaaaa"
or
"a"
"b"
"c"
...
"aa"
"ab"
"ac"
...
"aaaaa"
"aaaab"
"aaaac"
...
"abcde"
```

Comment: what output do you get?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: If you count your two iner loops out, you only get  len * 96  iterations in total. That is far too low to get all the 96^len combinations.

You need len nested loops (or something equivalent, most likely a recursive function) to get through all the combinations. Which, by the way, quickly becomes an outrageous number (with endlen 9, you get a few quadrillion strings).

Comment: could you think of them as base-26 numbers and start at 'a' go to 'zzz..'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `endlen` nested loops here.  You can avoid writing them explicitely by using a recursive approach:

```
void all_combinations( char* x, const int len )
{
    for (char c = 65; c < 70; ++c){
        x[len] = c;
        if (len>0){
            all_combinations( x, len - 1 );
        } else {
            printf( "%s\n", x );
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int maxlen = 3;
    char x[maxlen+1];
    for( int thislen=1; thislen<=maxlen; thislen++ ){
        x[thislen] = 0;
        all_combinations( x, thislen-1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain where the 65 and 70 come from?

Comment: Sorry. I don't think the point came across correctly. I need it to find all strings from length=1 to length=len. This includes (say len=5) "a" and "aaaaa".

Comment: then you can just run `all_combinations` in loop giving as last argument `1,2,..,len`.

Comment: The 65 and 70 correspond to your 32 and 127, I modified them to keep the output readable.  I adjusted the code in order to create strings of different length.